# Use powershell to get group membership for all users in an OU?

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am all new to powershell but I hope there is a way to get group membership for all users in a specified OU. 
For example, if I want to know which groups all users in OU "Users", are member of, without typing their sames. Is it possible? It would also be great if I could get it presentated in a list.

Thanks

Comment: Just imagining the output of this, I would think that this would be a hard list to understand.  Are you imagining that for each user, you'd see their name and then a column with each group they're a member of?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Get-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) in the `ActiveDirectory` module.

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'CN=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com' -Properties MemberOf
```

You can then format the output however you want.

Note that if you want a recursive group membership -- i.e., all groups that a user is a member of and all groups those groups are members of -- then the logic changes, and you have to do a lookup for each user:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'CN=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com' -Properties MemberOf, DistinguishedName;
$Users | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})" -f $_.DistinguishedName);
}
```

Obviously, you'd have to do some manipulation to keep the user and and groups together, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.